# Unix 'at' command does not respect the queue

Tags: unix, queue

I generate .sh scripts that I want to execute as jobs one after the other.
To achieve that, I just use the at command :

```
echo 'sh myscript1.sh' | at -q a now
echo 'sh myscript2.sh' | at -q a now
echo 'sh myscript3.sh' | at -q a now
               .
               .
               .
```

Instead of running the scripts one by one after the previous has finished, I found that the system fires up all of them at the time that they enter the queue.

What is going on?
Centos 7.1, with four cores.

OMG. It works in ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use Gnu Parallel that has a simple queue implementation

[LINK TO GNU PARALLEL MANUAL](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-queue-system-batch-manager)